# Does enabling hardware x86 virtualization (AMD-V or Intel VT-x) slow down my computer if I'm not running virtual machines?

Tags: virtualization

Does enabling hardware x86 virtualization (AMD-V or Intel VT-x) slow down my computer?

Obviously, it improves the performance if I'm running virtual machines, but what if I'm *not* running any VMs?

Comment: The Spector and Meltdown OS patches probably has a bigger negative impact on your system speed than enabling VT-x or AMD-V.

Answer (score 6):

No it will not. Most of the recent processors are coming with VT facility and its enabled by default.

Comment: VT-x and VT-d are just extra instructions in your CPU.  Not using them has the same exact impact as not using any other instructions--none ;)

Answer (score 0):

*Note that I've read that turning on this feature can slow normal operations down by 10-12%, which is why it's normally turned off.*

This is a myth.